# permitir y ver contenido o ver mensaje al bloquear la localización del usuario al pulsar un boton

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, geolocalización

A ver como explico esto, estoy tratando de que cuando un usuario pulse un boton le pregunte si desea guardar la localización o no, al pulsar el boton de permitir debería realizar lo que contiene dentro del boton, pero si por el contrario pulsamos a bloquear mostrará un mensaje hasta que usuario decida aceptar la geolocalización.(se realiza todo con el mismo boton es decir al pulsarlo si no hay permiso pregunta, y si ya se ha concedido o denegado muestra el contenido de permitir o de bloquear)

```js
$("#button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var main=document.querySelector("main");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos=>{
        main.textContent=`Latitud: ${pos.coords.latitude},` +
        `Longitud: ${pos.coords.longitude}`
      });
if (localizacion == true){
  let $mensaje = $("<p>a aceptado la localización</p>");
    function Carga(t) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve($("body").append("fetchs, funciones y otras cosas");
        }, t);
      });
    }
    async function esperar(t) {
      $("body").append($mensaje);
      await Carga(t);
    }
    esperar(5000);
} else {
    $("body").append("Debe aceptar la geolocalización");
  }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button id="button">Notificaciones</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

***He insertado en un snippet el codigo pero supongo que no está soportada la geolocalización por si no funciona.***

Comment: Falta cerrar un paréntesis en `resolve(...)`. Aparte, no se entiende bien lo que quieres hacer, porque intentas obtener un elemento `main`, que no existe en HTML (ni etiqueta, ni ID; ni clase), tampoco defines la variable `localizacion;` tienes una variable `$mensaje` que dudo pueda crearse como esperas, debería ser una simple cadena.

Comment: dame un momento editare la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enfocando la respuesta exclusivamente en [geolocalización](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation), debes tener en cuenta que, dependiendo del navegador, solo está disponible sobre protocolo seguro:

> **Secure context**
> This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.

El método [getCurrrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) acepta 3 parámetros, pero solo necesitamos 2:

1. Función que se ejecuta si se pudo obtener la ubicación
2. Función que se ejecuta en caso de error

```js
$("#button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Verificar que el navegador puede acceder a ubicación
    if(!('geolocation' in navigator)) {
        console.log('Opción no disponible');
        return;
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
        // Mostrar ubicación en contenedor con id="main"
        $('#main').text(`Latitud: ${pos.coords.latitude}, Longitud: ${pos.coords.longitude}`);
        $('body').append('<p>Ha aceptado la localización</p>');

        // Aquí mismo deberías ejecutar los otros procesos necesarios
        // De preferencia, llamando a funciones ya definidas

    }, err => {
        $('body').append('<p>Debe aceptar la localización</p>');
        console.log('Error obteniendo localización: ' + err.message);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="main"></div>
  <button id="button">Notificaciones</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: justo era eso millones de gracias!!!